# How do I reactivate the Unity hotkeys?

Tags: 11.10, unity, shortcut-keys

After some reboots (2-4) most of the hot-keys don't work any longer.

Hot-keys such as:

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

no longer work, but:

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> ... , <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment suggests that you are running Unity 2D and not Unity, so Compiz shortcuts like <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> won't do a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to reset unity settings to default:

```
unity --reset
```

That might fix it for you.

BTW, I don't think <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> does anything, it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't solve the problem
but i get a warning : 
     
"Warnung der Fensterverwaltung: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x3c00013 (unity-2d-p)
Warnung der Fensterverwaltung: meta_window_activate called by a pager with a 0 timestamp; the pager needs to be fixed."
   
it's a 3 day old install and i din't change many things